# Value stored to 'touch' during its initialization is never read

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am new to iPhone devlopment and i have a follwing clarification

```
- ( void )touchesEnded: ( NSSet * )touches withEvent: ( UIEvent * )event
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
{   
    if( !mouseSwiped ) 
    {
        UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

        // Enumerates through all touch object
        for (touch in touches)
        {
            // Sends to the dispatch method, which will make sure the appropriate subview is acted upon
            [self dispatchTouchAtPoint:[touch locationInView:self.view] :touches :nil];     
        }
    }
}
```

and when i run the static analyser for my application, i get the following

```
 Value stored to 'touch' during its initialization is never read
```

i am not what does it mean...

Please guide me out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do a `for each` loop, you must declare 'touch' within the parenthesis like this:

```
for (UITouch *touch in [touches allObjects]) {
            // Sends to the dispatch method, which will make sure the appropriate subview is acted upon
            [self dispatchTouchAtPoint:[touch locationInView:self.view] :touches :nil];     
}
```